# Test REST Delete Method using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-rest

I need help in using the right syntax for Mockito to test the Spring Rest Template Delete Method.

**Service Code:**

```
@Override
    public Boolean deleteCustomerItem(String customerNumber, String customerItemId)
            throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
        uriVariables.put("itemId", customerItemId);
        try {
            ResponseEntity<Void> deleteResponseEntity = restTemplate.exchange( deleteCustomerItemUrl, HttpMethod.DELETE, HttpEntity.EMPTY,
                    Void.class, uriVariables);
            return deleteResponseEntity.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AppCustomerException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Unit Test Code:**

```
@Test
    public void testDeleteCustomerItem() throws AppCustomerException {
        ResponseEntity<Void> noResponse = new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
        when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString(), any(HttpMethod.class), any(HttpEntity.class), Void.class, anyMap()))
                .thenReturn(noResponse);
        Boolean deleteStatus = appCustomerService.deleteCustomerItem("134", "7896");
        assertEquals(Boolean.TRUE, deleteStatus);
    }
```

**Exception:**

Invalid use of Mockito Matchers. 5 matchers expected 4 recorded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the `Void.class` within a Mockito matcher:

```
 when(restTemplate.exchange(
      anyString(), any(HttpMethod.class), any(HttpEntity.class), 
      eq(Void.class), anyMap()))
 .thenReturn(noResponse);
```

The way it works is that all the inputs are `ArgumentMatcher` wrapped or none.

Answer (score 1):

```
 when(restTemplate.exchange(
      anyString(), any(HttpMethod.class), any(HttpEntity.class), 
      any(Void.class), anyMap()))
 .thenReturn(noResponse);
```

- you should not combine ant matchers such anyMap() and anyString()
  with exact values like eq(Void.class) in when().thenReturn() statement
- also you can replace "Void.class" with any()

Comment: I agree. I should replace Void.class with any(). Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: if my answer helps you, please upvote it to be more visible to others @Suresh